# Node.js 'fs' throws an ENOENT error after adding auto-generated Swagger server code

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, fs

#### Preamble

To start off, I'm not a developer; I'm just an analyst / product owner with time on their hands. While my team's *actual* developers have been busy finishing off projects before year-end I've been attempting to put together a very basic API server in Node.js for something we will look at next year.

I used Swagger to build an API spec and then used the Swagger code generator to get a basic Node.js server. The full code is near the bottom of this question.

#### The Problem

I'm coming across an issue when writing out to a log file using the `fs` module. I know that the ENOENT error is usually down to just specifying a path incorrectly, but the behaviour *doesn't occur when I comment out the Swagger portion* of the automatically generated code. (I took the logging code directly out of another tool I built in Node.js, so I'm fairly confident in that portion at least...)

When executing `npm start`, a few debugging items write to the console:

> ```
> "Node Server Starting......
> Current Directory:/mnt/c/Users/USER/Repositories/PROJECT/api
> Trying to log data now! 
>  Mock mode: disabled 
> PostgreSQL Pool created successfully
> Your server is listening on port 3100 (http://localhost:3100)
> Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:3100/docs"
> ```

but then `fs` throws an ENOENT error:

> ```
> events.js:174
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
>  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../logs/logEvents2021-12-24.log'
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:277:12)
>     at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
> ```

##### Investigating

Now normally, from what I understand, this would just mean I've got the paths wrong. However, the file has actually been created and the [first line of the log file has been written just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0yxR.png)

My next thought was that I must've set the `fs` flags incorrectly, but it was set to 'a' for append:

```
var logsFile = fs.createWriteStream(__logdir+"/logEvents"+dateNow()+'.log',{flags: 'a'},(err) =>{
                    console.error('Could not write new Log File to location: %s \nWith error description: %s',__logdir, err);
                });
```

##### Removing Swagger Code

Now here's the weird bit: if I remove the Swagger code, the log files write out just fine and I don't get the `fs` exception!
This is the specific Swagger code:

```
// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
    routing: {
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers')
    },
};

var expressAppConfig = oas3Tools.expressAppConfig(path.join(__dirname, '/api/openapi.yaml'), options);
var app = expressAppConfig.getApp();


// Initialize the Swagger middleware
http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.info('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.info('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
}).on('error',console.error);
```

When I comment out this code, the log [file writes out just fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAT2F.png)

The only thing I can think that might be happening is that somehow Swagger is modifying (?) the app's working directory so that `fs` no longer finds the same file?

#### Full Code

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var oas3Tools = require('oas3-tools');
var serverPort = 3100;

// I am specifically tried using path.join that I found when investigating this issue, and referencing the app path, but to no avail

const __logdir = path.join(__dirname,'./logs');
//These are date and time functions I use to add timestamps to the logs
function dateNow(){
    var dateNow = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10).toString();
    return dateNow
}
function rightNow(){
    var timeNow = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0,8).toString();
    return "["+timeNow+"]  "
};

console.info("Node Server Starting......");
console.info("Current Directory: " + __dirname)

//  Here I create the WriteStreams

var logsFile = fs.createWriteStream(__logdir+"/logEvents"+dateNow()+'.log',{flags: 'a'},(err) =>{
                    console.error('Could not write new Log File to location: %s \nWith error description: %s',__logdir, err);
                });
var errorsFile = fs.createWriteStream(__logdir+"/errorEvents"+dateNow()+'.log',{flags: 'a'},(err) =>{
                    console.error('Could not write new Error Log File to location: %s \nWith error description: %s',__logdir, err);
                });

// And create an additional console to write data out:

const Console = require('console').Console;
var logOut = new Console(logsFile,errorsFile);
console.info("Trying to log data now!") // Debugging logging
logOut.log("========== Server Startup Initiated ==========");
logOut.log(rightNow() + "Server Directory: "+ __dirname);
logOut.log(rightNow() + "Logs directory: "+__logdir);

// Here is the Swagger portion that seems to create the behaviour. 
//   It is unedited from the Swagger Code-Gen tool

// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
    routing: {
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers')
    },
};

var expressAppConfig = oas3Tools.expressAppConfig(path.join(__dirname, '/api/openapi.yaml'), options);
var app = expressAppConfig.getApp();


// Initialize the Swagger middleware
http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.info('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.info('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
}).on('error',console.error);
```

In case it helps, this is the [project's file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzFiC.png) . I am running this project within a WSL instance in VSCode on Windows, same as I have with other projects using `fs`.

Is anyone able to help me understand why `fs` can write the first log line but then break once the Swagger code gets going? Have I done something incredibly stupid?
Appreciate the help, thanks!

Edit: Tried to fix broken images.

Comment: To clarify: the Swagger code is directly out of the code-generator - I was in the process of just trying to figure out how it is all supposed to work when I ran into this issue...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I tried to reproduce the error, but it isn't possible without the controller's JavaScript file and the YAML Swagger file.

Comment: Thanks @0x1C1B will do so in future.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem with some help from a friend. The issue boiled down to a lack of understanding of how the Swagger module works in the background, so this will likely be eye-rollingly obvious to most, but keeping this post around in case anyone else comes across this down the line.

So it seems that as part of the Swagger initialisation, any scripts within the `utils` folder will also be executed. I would not have picked up on this if it wasn't pointed out to me that in the middle of the console output there was a reference to some PostgreSQL code, even though I had taken all reference to it out of the main `index.js` file.

That's when I realised that the error wasn't actually being generated from the code posted above: it was being thrown from [image: another file I had added previously] to that folder.

So I guess the answer is don't add stuff to the `utils` folder, but if you do, always add a bunch of console logging...